# Codeigniter query not returning any result if records size more than 4MB

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, sqlsrv

```
$query = $this->db->query($qry, $qryParam); 
print_r($query);
```

This simple query is not returning any results (blank) if record size is more than 4MB. If the records is smaller than 4MB, `$query` is returning result.

No log error ini PHP and NGINX.

Spec: Nginx, PHP7.2-FPM, Codeigniter, sqlsrv

Comment: What is the statement and which version of the driver (`sqlsrv`) do you use? Thanks.

Comment: What's your sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize configuration set to? It's meant to default to 10240 (KB) but sounds like yours could be set lower.

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning, I solved the problem by set sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize = 50240,  but I can't find in my configuration that override the default value.